# Powershell Single row datatable return to fill combobox

Tags: sql, powershell, combobox, powershell-4.0

I'm in Powershell v4.0. I have a dropdown on my UI that I am filling with data from my database. I call a function that grabs the data like so:

`$ConfigDynamicContractID.ItemsSource = (GetDynamicContracts).DefaultView`

On the backend it looks like this:

```
function GetDynamicContracts{
    $ContractQuery = "select con.ContractNumber as Name, c.ContractID from foo..campaign c inner join foo..campaigntemplate ct on c.campaignid = ct.campaignid
inner join foo..template t on ct.templateid = t.templateid inner join bar..contracts con on con.ContractID = c.ContractID 
    where c.ProductType = 'INTRO' and t.FileName = 'Intro Dynamic Template' and c.DeleteFlag = 0"

    $ContractResult = ExecuteSelect "Bar" $ContractQuery
    return , $ContractResult
}
```

This code works fine. I was then told that the tables referenced above can't talk to each other so I have to do individual calls to each and filter in powershell. So here is my code for that:

```
function GetDynamicContracts{

    $CampaignQuery = "Select c.* From foo..Campaign c join foo..CampaignTemplate ct on c.CampaignID = ct.CampaignID
                    join foo..Template t on ct.TemplateID = t.TemplateID
                    Where c.ProductType = 'INTRO' and t.FileName = 'Intro Dynamic Template' and c.DeleteFlag = 0"
    $CampaignResults = ExecuteSelect "foo" $CampaignQuery

    $ContractIDs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    foreach($row in $CampaignResults.Rows){
        $ContractIDs.Add($row.ContractID)
    }
    $ContractIDs = $ContractIDs -join ","

    $PHQuery = "Select ContractID, ContractNumber as Name From Contracts Where ContractID in ($ContractIDs)"
    $PHResults = ExecuteSelect "Bar" $PHQuery

    #Log $MyInvocation.MyCommand $PSBoundParameters
    return ,$PHResults
}
```

This code for some reason does not work when returning a single row. But if I break this function call into two separate, then it works. See below:

```
function GetDynamicContracts{

    $ContractIDs = GetDynamicCampaign
    $ContractIDs = $ContractIDs[1]

    $PHQuery = "Select ContractID, ContractNumber as Name From Contracts Where ContractID in ($ContractIDs)"
    $PHResults = ExecuteSelect "PhytelMaster" $PHQuery

    Log $MyInvocation.MyCommand $PSBoundParameters
    return ,$PHResults
}

function GetDynamicCampaign{

    $CampaignQuery = "Select c.* From Campaign..Campaign c join Campaign..CampaignTemplate ct on c.CampaignID = ct.CampaignID
                    join Campaign..Template t on ct.TemplateID = t.TemplateID
                    Where c.ProductType = 'INTRO' and t.FileName = 'Intro Dynamic Template' and c.DeleteFlag = 0"
    $CampaignResults = ExecuteSelect "Campaign" $CampaignQuery

    $ContractIDs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    foreach($row in $CampaignResults.Rows){
        $ContractIDs.Add($row.ContractID)
    }
    $ContractIDs = $ContractIDs -join ","

    return $ContractIDs
}
```

It seems that making two execute selects in a single function causes the ',' to fail to do what it does when returning the data. Can anyone explain why?? Thanks ahead of time and since I have a workaround there is no rush.

Comment: ArrayList.add spams in output with the added item index, and AFAIK it should always be suppressed regardless of `return` statements with `> $null` or `| Out-Null`. Just saying.

Comment: PowerShell functions output everything to the pipeline that is not otherwise redirected. Using the `Return` keyword is redundant and superfluous. So when I lookup the `Add` method of an `ArrayList` ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) it shows that the method outputs the index of the item added. Unless that is redirected you will get that `Int` output to the pipeline in addition to anything else you may want.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. This is rather annoying aspect of Powershell. I found in another thread that if I wrap the code in my function with $null = @{ 'do code' } and then at the end when I do the return (return $a) then only $a returns. It's ugly, but seems to guarantee no hanky panky with powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TheMadTechnician and @wOxxOm point out ArrayList spams the indexes into the return and return, returns everything that gets spammed in the function. So when I expected $PHResults I also got the ArrayList spam. I could use something other than the ArrayList or I also found that if I wrap my function code in `$null = @{ 'Code' }` and then return the variable I want, all I get is that variable. It's ugly but it works.